# Laravel Fluent Query Builder Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I want to add two columns while using update, like this:

```
 Update purchase_stock inner join stock on purchase_stock.fkstockid=stock.stockid SET currentavailable=currentavailable+subquantity where fkorderid='1';
```

Here is the current Fluent code:

```
 DB::table('purchase_stock')->join('stock','stock.stockid','=','purchase_stock.fkstockid')->where('fkorderid',$orderId)->update(array('currentavailable'=>'currentavailable'+'subquantity'));**
```

But it throws error as below:

```
"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"syntax error, unexpected '=>'"
```

Does any one have solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohk!
I already tried this one but it is not working 
As of now I am using `DB::statement('')` and it's working
So I have written whole update query within statement and it's working as somewhere I have read that it will not be helpful to return result set but will work with insert or update.

Comment: It's not a best practice

Answer (score 1):

You were very close with your fluent attempt, but there were two issues:

1. The plus sign needs to be inside the quotes, since you want the math done in SQL, not in PHP.
2. Need a `DB::raw()` around the value so Laravel doesn't think you're actually trying to set it to the string `"currentavailable + subquantity"`

So the final product looks like this:

```
DB::table('purchase_stock')
    ->join('stock', 'stock.stockid', '=', 'purchase_stock.fkstockid')
    ->where('fkorderid', $orderId)
    ->update(['currentavailable' => DB::raw('currentavailable + subquantity')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Мaybe you need to  set these two fields from which tables. Exampl. `DB::table('purchase_stock')->join('stock','stock.stockid','=','purchase_stock.fkstockid')->where('fkorderid',$orderId)->update(array('stock.currentavailable'=>'stock.currentavailable'+'stock.subquantity'));`